# Accessing Base64 part of a string added to a .txt file using list slicing [PYTHON]

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the base64 part of b'ZExxZEtVbUs=' which is located in the "log.txt" file, I've tried using list slicing but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
import base64

target = open("log.txt", "r")

for line in target:
    #print(line)
    stringarray = [line]
    stringver = str(stringarray[1:14])
    print(base64.b64decode(stringver))
```

Comment: I'm trying to access ZExxZEtVbUs= from b'ZExxZEtVbUs='  in order to decode it.

Comment: str(b'ZExxZEtVbUs=').strip('b').strip("'") gives 'ZExxZEtVbUs=' as a string

Comment: `b'ZExxZEtVbUs='.decode()` should give you the string `'ZExxZEtVbUs='`

Comment: @Tris-Nefzger, your method returns this ZExxZEtVbUs=' with a single apostrophe at the end, do you have a fix for this?

Comment: I am using python 3.4.3 and with that it quotes the result as I showed giving the same result as using decode().  However running base64.b64decode() on thatg gives the same result as running it on the original b'ZExxZEtVbUs='.

Comment: Thanks, after you explained what you did, I looked over what I was doing and the method you shared did work, many thanks once again!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
stringarray = [line]
```

This line doesn't make the line of the text file into an array of characters, but rather an array with a single string element.  Although I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want, it seems like this line is the problem.

I feel like you could do something like this instead:

```
for line in target:
    #print(line)
    print(base64.b64decode(line[1:14]))
```

Further expanding my example and dropping the unneeded `14` from the slice operation gives this input and output:

```
import base64

target = ["b'ZExxZEtVbUs='"]

for line in target:
    print(line)
    print(line[1:])
    print(base64.b64decode(line[1:]))

#OUTPUT:
b'ZExxZEtVbUs='
'ZExxZEtVbUs='
dLqdKUmK
```

Comment: That prints b'ZExxZEtVbUs=' instead of  ZExxZEtVbUs which is the part of the string that I'm trying to access in order to base64decode it.

Comment: I've added an additional example which you can run at any Python window.  @Fuzew let me know if that doesn't work for you.